# Laravel: rating system Javascript display

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

I'm making a review system. I'm done with the post, but the get and display wont perfectly work.  Can you please help me with this.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="aa" value="{{$re->rating}}" />
<div id="d"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var wrapper2 = document.getElementById("d");
var rating = 0;
var myHTML2 = '';
var rating = document.getElementById("aa").value;
var nonee= 0;
nonee = 5 - rating;

for (var w = 0; w <rating; w++) {
    myHTML2 += '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>';
}
for (var e = 0; e <nonee; e++) {
    myHTML2 += '<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>';
}  

wrapper2.innerHTML = myHTML2;
```

The result should be three reviews along with the rating but it will only display the rating in the first review, the rest none.

Comment: I think there's something I'm not getting. isn't the code actually written to retrieve only one review?

Comment: that's the point idk how to get all the ratings from the databse along with users

Answer (score 0):

Your solution can only be used to show 1 rating/review. If you need to show more reviews, you need to modify it with some iterations/loops.

If you don't use AJAX for fetching more reviews, you can just loop through all the reviews with blade template since you're using laravel.

```php
@foreach($ratings as $re)
  <div class="d">
  @for($i = 0; $i < $re->rating; $re++)
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
  @endfor
  @for($i = 0; $i < 5 - $re->rating; $re++)
    <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
  @endfor
  </div>
@endforeach
```

---

If you're using AJAX, you can format the output of your ratings with JSON like such:

```
[
  {"review_id":1, "rating":3, "review":"not so bad"},
  {"review_id":2, "rating":5, "review":"good"},
  {"review_id":3, "rating":5, "review":"perfect"}
]
```

and decode it with javascript, then let javascript handle the HTML generation:

```html
<div id="containerRating"></div>
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: "http://...",
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data){
    var ratings = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var i=0; i<ratings.length; i++) {
      var ratingHtml = "<div class='review'>";
      for (var j=0; j<ratings[i]; j++) {
        ratingHtml = ratingHtml + "<span class='fa fa-star'></span>"
      }
      for (var j=0; j<5-ratings[i]; j++) {
        ratingHtml = ratingHtml + "<span class='fa fa-star-o'></span>"
      }
      ratingHtml = ratingHtml + "</div>"
      $("#containerRating").append(ratingHtml);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: var wrapper2 = document.getElementById("d");
var rating = 0;
var myHTML2 = '';
var rating = document.getElementsByName('aa[]');

for (var i = 0; i <rating.length; i++) {
var inp=rating[i];
var ra=inp.value;
nonee = 5 - ra;
 for (var w = 0; w <ra; w++) {
   myHTML2 += '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>';
}for (var e = 0; e <nonee; e++) {
    myHTML2 += '<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>';
}  

}
wrapper2.innerHTML = myHTML2;

Comment: i used this and it dislay all the ratings tho the only problem it displays on the first review only all the ratings

Comment: @Venus Is it correct if I assume that "rating" means whole number with 1<=rating<=5, and "review" means text?

Comment: which one didn't display properly? is it the ratings (number) or the reviews (text)?

Comment: can i message you directly it's so hard to exlain without letting you see the outut

Answer (score 0):

try this. i used modal here because its been tested with modal. you can change it to out on a non modal. the result is display on a table using ajax :

```
<div id="view" class="modal fade" >
            <div class="modal-dialog box box-default" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#4287f5;color:white">
                  <p class="modal-title">Record</p>

                </div>
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post"  role="form">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="modal-body">  
                   <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="tableID" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
                    <thead>

                    </thead>

                    <tbody style="margin-left:10px;">

                    </tbody>

                  </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color:#4287f5;color:white">
                        <button type="button" id="btnclose" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                    </form>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
```

//ajax

```
<script>
     function getResult(x)
   {

        var ID = x;
        //alert(ID);
        $.get('/url?recordID='+ID, function(data){
         var html = '';
              html +='<tr bgcolor="#c7c7c7" align="center">';
              html +='<th align="center">Review</th>';
              html +='<th align="center">Ratings</th>';
              html +='</tr>';
          $.each(data,function(index,obj){

              html +='<tr>';
              html +='<td>'+ obj.review+'</td>';

              html +='<td>'+ obj.ratings+'</td>';
              }
              html +='</tr>';
              $('#tableID').html(html);
          });


         });
         $("#view").modal('show')
   }

</script>
```